# Docker Compose Failing for command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:8u222_1.3.5_2.13.1
WORKDIR /code/SimpleStocks
COPY ./SimpleStocks .
RUN sbt dist
WORKDIR /code/SimpleStocks/target/universal
RUN unzip simplestocks-0.0.1.zip
WORKDIR /code/SimpleStocks/target/universal/simplestocks-0.0.1
CMD ["bin/simplestocks"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    container_name: simple-stocks
    image: simple-stocks:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links:
      - pgdb1
  pgdb1:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: simple_stocks
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdb1data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./docker_postgres_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker_postgres_init.sql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
volumes:
  pgdb1data:
```

When I manually run simple-stocks container using docker run -it {imageId}, I am able to run it successfully; but, on doing docker compose up I am receiving:

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "bin/simplestocks": stat bin/simplestocks: no such file or directory:
> unknown

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile is building the application in `/code/SimpleStocks/target/universal/simplestocks-0.0.1`, but then your Compose file bind-mounts a host directory over `/code`, which hides everything the Dockerfile does.  The bind mount is unnecessary and deleting it will resolve this issue.

Bind-mounting a host directory over your entire built application usually is not a best practice.  I most often see it trying to convince Docker to emulate a local development environment, but even that approach doesn't make sense for a compiled language like Scala.

You can safely remove the `volumes:` block.  The obsolete `links:` can also be removed.  You don't need to manually specify `container_name:`, nor do you need to specify both `build:` and `image:` unless you're planning to push the built image to a registry.  That would reduce the Compose setup to just:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
  pgdb1: (as in the question originally)
volumes:
  pgdb1data:
```

Comment: My use case is to create a local dev environment and I need to sync my host source code with the docker container. So is there any way to do it with docker-compose or I have to locally install all dependencies in one docker container

Comment: You can just [install sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) and [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/); you don't need to introduce an isolation environment like Docker, then try to disable its isolation features.  Also look at [sbt-native-packager](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as a tool to build Docker images without managing the Dockerfile yourself.  This will not be a live development environment, and that's not really Docker's strength IMHO.